# news iphone app that reads from online database

Tags: ios, objective-c, feed

I have a Wordpress blog that displays scientific news.
I need to create an iPhone app, news reader that reads from the same MySQL database online of the website. Any ideas if I can find a tutorial that can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress has an [XML-RPC and AtomPub web api](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-started-with-xml-rpc-or-atom-publising-protocal).  That would allow you to make http calls from iOS using NSURLConnection or another http api.  For that you would use [NSXMLParser](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html) on the iOS side.

If you need to query your data out of a MySQL database, then I would strongly recommend putting an http web api on top of it using something like [ASP.net web api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations), [PHP](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/09/23/short-list-of-restful-api-frameworks-for-php/), [node.js](http://pixelhandler.com/blog/2012/02/09/develop-a-restful-api-using-node-js-with-express-and-mongoose/) etc...

The http server could return json as the data and in iOS 5 and beyond, there's a JSON parser: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: Thank you Bryan, that sounds logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an RSS widget to your blog then the iPhone app would consume that - see [how to make a simple rss reader iphone app tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial)